# Unable to connect Express application with Redis container

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I have Redis running locally on Docker container. I am trying to connect my Express application with Redis container but unable to connect.

Below is my code:

**redi.js**

```
const redis = require('redis');

const redisCon = () => {

const client = redis.createClient('6379','127.0.0.1');

client.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('Connected!');
});

}

module.exports = redisCon;
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const config = require("config");
const redisCon = require('./redi');

const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 2222;

redisCon;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`Current ip is ${ip}`);
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is running at ${port}`));
```

What I am doing wrong in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

The arguments you are giving `.createClient` are incorrect. Furthermore, and you are not connecting to Redis, just creating the client.

See the follow for some examples on how to create a client. And on how to connect that client to Redis:

```js
import { createClient } from 'redis';

/* Create a Redis client that *will* connect
   to localhost on port 6379 in one of these ways */
const client = createClient();
const client = createClient({ url: 'redis://localhost:6379' });
const client = createClient({ socket: { host: '127.0.0.1', port: 6379 } });

/* log any errors */
client.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));

/* connect to Redis and wait for it to be established */
await client.connect();
```

There are a lot of arguments you can use when creating a client. You can read about them [here](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/master/docs/client-configuration.md).